# Sum with variable range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, sum

I try following VBA Programming, but its formula in excel cell is `"=SUM('F12':'F91')"` which ' mark can not remove. Can anyone teach me what's problem in my following program?

```
Sub Step7()

' Step 7 : Insert S code for VBA formula Input

' S - Subtotal

' Prepare formula to each Code

Dim c1, c2 As Long

    c1 = 2

    For i = 2 To 9999

        If Range("H" & i).Value <> "s" Then

           c2 = i - 1

        ElseIf Range("H" & i).Value = "s" Then

            Range("F" & i).Select

            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(F" & c1 & ":F" & c2 & ")"

           c1 = c2

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveCell.Formula`.... You're using A1 notation, not R1C1 notation, so you should use `.Formula`, not `.FormulaR1C1`.

Comment: You have not defined the variable for "i", unless it is defined elsewhere.